# NodeJS export variables from redis query

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to be able to export variables for a module by querying the values from redis, however I cannot figure out how to do this asynchronously.

This is what I have tried, where getconfig() is a function that returns variables queried from redis:

```
var exports = {};
module.exports = exports;

getconfig(function(config){ 
    exports.ConnectionString = {
        Server: config.db.server,
        Login: config.db.userName,
        Database: config.db.database,
        Password: config.db.password,
        Port: 1433,
        Timeout:10000
    };
    exports.poolSize = 1000;
    exports.poolIdleTimeout = 30000000;
    exports.tdsServerPort = 88888;
    console.log(exports);

})
```

But this does not work. How can I return these export variables ?

I have tried the suggestion from @Peter Lyons using the following simplified example:

```
module.exports = {
    ConnectionString: getDb,
    poolSize: 1000,
    poolIdleTimeout: 30000000,
    tdsServerPort: 88888
}

function getDb(cb){
    var dat = {
        Server:'192.168.42.4',
        Login: 'XXXX',
        Database: 'MYDB',
        Password: 'PASS',
        Port: 1433,
        Timeout:10000
    };

    cb(null,dat);

}
```

but when it is called, it returns the connection string as a function and is not evaluated:

```
{ ConnectionString: [Function: getDb],
  poolSize: 1000,
  poolIdleTimeout: 30000000,
  tdsServerPort: 88888 }
```

Comment: `require` is synchronous. Database calls are asynchronous. That's your fundamental problem you need to address. In your 2nd snippet you reference `getDb` without parens, so it doesn't execute, and there's also no callback so even if it did execute it wouldn't work like you hope.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are for code and static data. Functions, constants, etc. Data from databases does not belong as module exports. It's extremely unconventional and somewhat illogical. What IS conventional and straightforward, however, is a function that queries and database and invokes a callback with the results.

```
function getConnectionString(callback) {
  getConfigFromRedis(function (error, config) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error)
      return
    }
    var connectionString = {
      Server: config.db.server,
      ......etc
    }
    callback(null, connectionString)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getConnectionString: getConnectionString
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes the problem I am facing is that the developer of the module is reading configuration settings from an imported module, however all of my configuration data is stored in REDIS. I can of cours ehack their module, but so far with this application I have not hacked any modules so that I can upgrade with out problems.

Comment: Can you get the settings from redis in a wrapper script and then set them as environment variables before executing your application?

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know why the connection string above is returned as a function and is not evaluated ??

Comment: Yes, because you don't have a pair of parentheses there. But with regard to the larger conceptual issue here I don't think we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using another module that works like this:

```
var my_module = require('my_module');
var thing = require('thing')(my_module);
```

If that's the case, you'll have to wrap your code somehow, either how Peter Lyons described in his answer comment, or like this.

```
/////// in your module ///////
module.exports = {
    ConnectionString: {},
    poolSize: 1000,
    poolIdleTimeout: 30000000,
    tdsServerPort: 88888
}

function setup(cb){
  // just using GET to simplify because I have no idea how your db is set up
  redis_client.get('connection_data_key', function(err, result) {
    exports.ConnectionString = result;
    cb(err);
  }.bind(this));
}


////// in your main code //////
var my_module = require('my_module');
my_module.setup(function(err) {
  var thing = require('thing')(my_module);
  // the rest of your code dependent on 'thing' goes here
});
```